# Trying to understand inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I feel I have a decent understanding of inheritance in Java but am struggling with the following situation:

```
public class SuperClass {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public SuperClass(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void sharedMethod() {
        System.out.println("I'm a shared method in the SuperClass");
    }

}


public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    public SubClass(String name, int age) {
        super(name, age);
    }

    public void sharedMethod() {
        System.out.println("I'm a shared method in the SubClass");
    }

    public void subMethod() {
        System.out.println("I'm subMethod");
    }

}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SuperClass test = new SubClass("Laura", 30);

        test.sharedMethod();

        test.subMethod(); // causes an error
    }
}
```

I am primarily struggling to understand what is actually being created here when using `SuperClass test = new SubClass("Laura", 30);` (which only seems to work when `SubClass` extends `SuperClass` - how's that possible without Casting?).

The reason I don't understand it is because I can call the `sharedMethod` which prints out the text from the `SubClass` method (so presumably `SubClass` is overriding the `SuperClass` method in this instance), but yet I can't call the `subMethod` from the `SubClass` at all. Sorry if I didn't articulate it very well, I just can't seem to wrap my head around what is being referenced, what methods can be used, why you would do this, why the `SubClass` overrides a method if the method is shared, but can't be called otherwise.

Comment: This is possible without casting, because every `SubClass` is also a `SuperClass` (due to the inheritance relationship). But since you reference thorugh a reference of type `SuperClass`, you can only see what is already defined in `SuperClass`. And yes, `SubClass` overwrites `sharedMethod()`.

Comment: Please notice that there is no cast in this situation, so test is still a SubClass getting accessed using the public interface of SuperClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `SuperClass test = new SubClass("Laura", 30)`, you create a `SubClass` instance, but reference it by `SuperClass`.

At compile stage, the compiler found that `SuperClass` does not have method `subMethod`, so you get compile error.

At runtime, JVM found that `test` is actually a `SubClass`, so the `sharedMethod` from `SubClass`:

```
public void sharedMethod() {
    System.out.println("I'm a shared method in the SubClass");
}
```

will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you had a you told somebody you had a vehicle:

```
class Vehicle {

  public void drive() {
    System.out.println("Driving vehicle");
  }
}
```

That means, the person you told knows you are capable of driving...But, then you got a motorcycle:

```
class Motorcycle extends Vehicle {

  public void wheely() {
    System.out.println("Doing a wheely");
  }

  public void drive() {
    System.out.println("Driving motorcycle");
  }
}
```

Which can `drive()` because its a `Vehicle`, and also do a `wheely()`. But, you never told them the type of vehicle you had was a motorcycle. So, the most they know you are capable of doing is driving.

The level of knowledge that the person has is similar to the object reference:

```
Vehicle vehicle = new Motorcycle();
```

The `Vehicle` reference only knows you are a `Vehicle`. It doesn't matter "HOW" you drive, it just knows that you know how to drive. So, when you call `drive()` it will drive how `Motorcycle` drives (overridden method), but you are still driving.

But, if you were to be more SPECIFIC and tell someone the type of vehicle you had was a motorcycle, you are giving them MORE information about the CAPABILITIES of your vehicle.

```
Motorcycle motorcycle = new Motorcycle();
```

You know since it's a `Vehicle` it still can do all that a vehicle can do `drive()`. But, since you now have a reference to the subclass, you know more about what it can do - `wheely()`.

The compiler cannot make assumptions, so if you make a reference `Vehicle v` that is LESS specific (a super class) the compiler will only access elements of that object that it KNOWS for sure it has access to. If you make a MORE specific reference (a sub class), then you are telling the compiler more about what that object can do.